# SQL Server Lock Escalation all tables are with "TABLE"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with deadlocks all the time. The application has more than 1000 tables and the amount of users are 100 in average.
When I checked the lock escalation type with this query, all tables are with "TABLE"

```
SELECT lock_escalation_desc FROM sys.tables
```

Is this the default behaviour? None with ROW or PAGE?
I checked another application in another server and all the tables are "TABLE" also.

Thanks.

Comment: it depend on your lock type, it seems your lock only on table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is the default **escalation** level and is perfectly normal.

Perhaps you are confused about what escalation is? This is what happens once SQL Server holds too many locks at a lower level and consolidates them for performance and resource reasons.

You would need to check `allow_row_locks` and `allow_page_locks` in `sys.indexes` to see if you have some configuration issue that is preventing these lower level locks being taken.

w.r.t. the escalation level itself if you use partitioned tables then you could instead consider `AUTO` to avoid locking the whole thing. But the reason this isn't the default is because against common workloads this turned out to be more deadlock prone.

Locks are never escalated from row to page. it always goes from row or page to at least the whole partition level.

You should investigate why you are seeing lock escalation in the first place (if indeed you are). Under read committed isolation level the typical behaviour is for select queries to take row locks and release them as soon as the data is read.

Are you running at unnecessarily restrictive isolation levels? Are these escalations happening to data modification statements that could be broken up into smaller batches?

Comment: The application is working with READ COMMITTED and the allow_row_locks and allow_page_locks are all with 1 from sys.indexes, but the select lock is always "TABLE". Thanks.

Comment: So what makes you believe that lock escalation is the problem?. It might be but that isn't evident from the information you have supplied so far. You've asked "is this the default behaviour?" answer "yes it is". So this seems to be an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask another question that actually asks the thing you need the answer to.